# Excel 2016 V look up with wild card for number within number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to use a `VLOOKUP` to find a number within a larger number.

I have the last 4 digit of employee ids and I need excel to return to me the entire employee ID for the directory.

For instance I currently have a employee's last 4 numbers 2000 and on the table the number is 1232000. I need `VLOOKUP` to bring back the 1232000 number for me. 
I have tried to use Vlookup like this

`=VLOOKUP("*"&C3,'List Station'!A:C,3,FALSE)`

but it only ever gives me N/A

Even though I know the numbers are there

Some employees have 3 different log in ID's so I have to have it match the last 4 numbers that I currently have,  I cannot use the name to look it up.

Comment: Are your employee ID's stored as number or text?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
{=INDEX('List Station'!C:C,MATCH(C3&"",RIGHT('List Station'!A:A,4),0),1)}
```

And enter it as an array formula using **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **Enter**

Only tested on VERY small sample
[image]